# Slide down, up animation only works for the first time in fragment

Tags: android, animation

I have implemented a slide_down and slide_up animation for my layout in my fragment. I have implemented that for a click in my MPAndroidChart bar chart. Problem is this works well for the first slide_down and slide_up click. For next clicks animation not working.

**slide_down.xml**

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

**slide_up.xml**

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/redPrimaryLight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSelMonth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMotor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNonMotor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**code**

I made the layout invisible inside onCreateView

```
textViewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

downAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_down);
upAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up);
```

Then barchart click....

```
    gBarChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            textViewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewLayout.setAnimation(downAnimation);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {
            textViewLayout.setAnimation(upAnimation);
            textViewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your chart every time whenever you show the chart. For that you need to call following line.

```
chartView.invalidate();
```